# How do I disable (or rein in) org-git-link (org-plus-contrib 20190513)?

Tags: git, emacs, org-mode

folks,

I'm running emacs 27 on Linux Mint 19.  Installed the latest `org-plus-contrib` package (20190513) from the Org repo this morning, and found that every subsequent attempt to store a link to an org-mode entry invoked `org-git-link.el` and produced a `[[git:]]` link, as described here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-git-link.html, instead of the "traditional" file+heading link to which I've become accustomed.

The doc cited above seems to imply that this is the "correct" (or at least the *intended*) behavior of the package....i.e., the `org-git-link` code knowingly overrides the default behavior of the `org-store-link` function.

My question is, how do you toggle this feature?  There doesn't seem to be an "opt-out" button.  The package seems to intercept **all** requests to store a link to an org heading, whether invoked via M-x, via expansion of a capture template token (`%a or %A`, for example), or even via the use of the menu-bar. I can't find a hook, toggle, or relevant user-customizable option anywhere.

Eventually I pulled down a fresh `emacs-snapshot` build, which shook off the `contrib` stuff and restored the expected functionality.  But I would like to know what, if anything, I've missed.

Thanks!

Comment: No, the doc says that in certain cases only, it adds a git: link to the list of stored links, so that you can select it when you do `C-c C-l`. But it is up to you to select it (or not). If it doesn't work that way, it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hesitant to say "bug" until/unless someone else duplicates the problem :-)  Thank you for looking it over.